# Markevery float, but with start/end

Tags: python, matplotlib

I would like to plot a line with markers, where the markers are every `0.2`, but also on the start and end point.

When I do `plt.plot(np.linspace(0, 0.95, 10), np.linspace(0, 0.95, 10), '-o', markevery=0.2)`, I do get a line with markers correctly spaced, but there is no marker at the end. I want to overrule the fixed distance of `0.2` and enforce a marker at the end. How would I do that?

Comment: Wouldn't it be easier to just manually draw the missing marker at the end in a second call to `plt` right after your plot?

Comment: You can [get](https://matplotlib.org/3.1.1/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.axes.Axes.get_xticks.html#matplotlib.axes.Axes.get_xticks) the ticks, append the  start and end points and then [set](https://matplotlib.org/3.1.1/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.axes.Axes.set_xticks.html#matplotlib.axes.Axes.set_xticks) them.

Comment: @GPhilo Let's say that my usecase is a bit complicated and I'd rather have a one line command that's very complicated, than something that involves "finding out where the end point is" (and then manually plotting the marker at that end point)

Comment: @FooBar : Why do you have to find out the end point? You already know it... It is the value 0.95 in your case. Even in your usecase, don't you know the value while using `linspace`?

Comment: @Sheldore My actual usecase is a self-build function that takes `x_grid`, `y_grid` and `**args`, cuts `x_grid` into several shorter grids and plots them with `**args`. I want to provide to that self-build function `**args` that fix the markers. I do not want to have any additional code inside my self-build function that takes for each of the shorter lines.

Comment: `markevery` allows to *either* specify the index of the points to mark, *or* the distance between them, not both at the same time. So you need to specify the index, in this case e.g. `markevery=[0,2,4,6,8,-1]`